# A different definition of bi-conditional proposition

Tags: logic, solution-verification, definition, propositional-calculus

The proposition "p iff q" known as the logical equivalence or biconditional in propositional logic is generally defined as:

$ p\iff q \\
\equiv (p\implies q)
\wedge (q\implies p)$

and is true only when either both p and q are true or both are false. The same can be easily verified using truth table.
But I came across a different definition also attached in the snap below :

$ p\iff q\\
\equiv 1- |p-q|$

I am trying to convince myself about this definition, any help to verify this definition using the usual definition would be helpful.

Snap of the above definition from [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bCGgswEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book's Pg 247

[image]

Comment: The issue is quite simple: when p and q have different truth values the formula outputs 0 while in the other two cases it outputs 1. And this is exactly the truth table of the biconditional.

Comment: Just consider all four cases for (p, q).  That is, the cases (p = 0, q = 0), (p = 0, q = 1), (p = 1, q = 0), and (p = 1, q = 1).

Comment: For the classical logic it's okay with me, but I am trying with fuzzy logic.. Will add the details soon.

Comment: How does this text define other connectives? I can't think of definitions for and/or/not that would result in the usual equivalences (and the link doesn't have the full text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know the book, but in fuzzy logic, usually classical **true** and **false** are mapped to **1** and **0** respectively and operators are defined to be consistent with their classic counterparts.

$\iff$ is **true** when both sides have the same truth value. When $p$ and $q$ are “absolutely true or absolutely false” (have classical truth values) $|{p-q}|$ will be **1** when they differ, and **0** when they are the same. Doing a “fuzzy not” by subtracting from **1** results in **1**, or **true** if and only if $p$ and $q$ have the same classical truth values.

So, yep, it looks consistent with the standard classic to fuzzy translation.

I’ll add that, what this really means when $p$ or $q$ is fuzzy, I can’t explain (but I can do the math).

Comment: Exactly why I was pondering about this..for the classical case I am fine, but I got an example where it is being applied in multi-valued logic.. I will get back and edit my question with the details..

Comment: I ask for def's of other connectives in a comment above. I've seen min for $\land$ and max for $\lor$, or some attempt to approximate probabilities assuming lhs is independent of rhs. I never got far with Fuzzy Logic (it was introduced with a lot of hype), but I'm curious now...

Answer (score 1):

The reference cited adopts a radically extensional point of view that amounts to identifying propositions with their reference / denotation, that is, with their truth -values, namely $1$ or $0$.

- $ (P\iff Q) \implies 1-|P-Q| =1 $

Suppose that we have $(P\iff Q)$, that is, by definition, $ P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow Q$.

It means we do not have :  $P=1$ and $Q=0$ , implying  that $P-Q \neq 1$.

It also means that we do not have $P=0$ and $Q=1$,  implying that $P-Q \neq -1$.

Since $P-Q$ is neither equal to $1$ nor  to $-1$ , $|P-Q|\neq 1$.

Therefore $1- |P-Q| \neq 0$, implying that  $1- |P-Q| = 1$.

- $1-|P-Q| =1 \implies (P\iff Q) $

If $1-|P-Q| =1$ , $|P-Q|$ must be equal to $0$ , and therefore, $P$ and $Q$ must have the same truth value, meaning  that $( P\iff Q) $ is true.